# Not able to create new oracle jdbc-source confluent kafka connector. It is giving error Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I have tested default existing jdbc source connector. It is working fine for DB. I want to create another oracle jdbc source connector for different DB. For that I have created new properties file with different DB details. Then, I ran the below command.

```
bin/connect-standalone etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-standalone.properties source-quickstart-sqlite1.properties
```

The Error:

```
[2020-06-20 09:43:46,751] ERROR Stopping due to error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:130)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Unable to initialize REST server
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer.initializeServer(RestServer.java:217)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:87)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8083
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:346)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:307)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:231)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:385)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer.initializeServer(RestServer.java:215)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:342)
        ... 8 more
```

I have tried usuing rest.port:8089. It is also not working.

Answer (score 1):

There is already an application running on you computer, who is attached (binded) to the port 8083. Probably, it's another Kafka Connect instance. Stop it before executing you command.

To find the app listening the port, execute [`lsof -i :8083`](https://debian-administration.org/article/184/How_to_find_out_which_process_is_listening_upon_a_port) and you'll get the PID. You can then simply [`kill`](https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/how-kill-process-command-line/) it, assuming it's all about local development of Konnect applications.